# Drawing a line with arrow in Java

Tags: java, graphics, awt

[image]Can anyone guide me how to code the arrow line in different direction. 
wa and wl is positive the rectangle will be on top of the x-axis. Below example shown if wl is negative and wa is positive. The code below shown how i code the rectangle shape. x1 is the varaible to state where to start at x axis. e1 is the length of the shape, wa1 and wl1 is the height. wsign to determine the height wa1 or wl1 should display at negative side or positive side.

```
        if (Math.abs(wl1) > Math.abs(wa1)) {
            y_scale = (load_y0 - 40) / (double) Math.abs(wl1);
        } else {
            y_scale = (load_y0 - 40) / (double) Math.abs(wa1);
        }
        g.drawLine((int) ((double) x0 + x1 * x_scale), (int) (load_y),
                    (int) ((double) x0 + x1 * x_scale),
                    (int) (load_y + (wa1 * y_scale) * -1));
            g.drawLine((int) ((double) x0 + (x1 + e1) * x_scale),
                    (int) (load_y), (int) ((double) x0 + (x1 + e1)
                            * x_scale), (int) (load_y + (wl1 * y_scale)
                            * -1));

            g.drawLine((int) ((double) x0 + x1 * x_scale),
                    (int) (load_y + (wa1 * y_scale * -1)),
                    (int) ((double) x0 + (x1 + e1) * x_scale),
                    (int) (load_y + (wl1 * y_scale) * -1));
```

Comment: That's too fast for me ))). What do you mean by "draw the line between the shape and the arrow direction"?

Comment: Can you annotate your diagram with a circle to show which line you mean?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I want to draw the line with arrow inside the triangle shape, one is shown at positive area another is shown at negative area

Comment: Hi maybe can you guide me how to get x when the point y = 0 like shown in diagram?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a simple routine (adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488419/java-draw-a-ruler-line-with-tick-marks-at-90-degree-angle/3488474#3488474)) for drawing arbitrary arrows:

```
import static java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame t = new JFrame();
        t.add(new JComponent() {

            private final int ARR_SIZE = 4;

            void drawArrow(Graphics g1, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();

                double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
                double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
                AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
                at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
                g.transform(at);

                // Draw horizontal arrow starting in (0, 0)
                g.drawLine(0, 0, len, 0);
                g.fillPolygon(new int[] {len, len-ARR_SIZE, len-ARR_SIZE, len},
                              new int[] {0, -ARR_SIZE, ARR_SIZE, 0}, 4);
            }

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                for (int x = 15; x < 200; x += 16)
                    drawArrow(g, x, x, x, 150);
                drawArrow(g, 30, 300, 300, 190);
            }
        });

        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(400, 400);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example, but how can i set the height of the line according wa1 and wl1

Comment: Hi maybe can you guide me how to get x when  the point y = 0 like shown in diagram?

Comment: great answer, but I can't get my head around what you would to to give the arrow an offset, for example, me second coordinate is the center of a circle, how would I change it so the arrow points to the circumference of the circle as opposed to the center?

Comment: The arrow-drawing code is trivial. It's the two lines below the `// Draw horizontal arrow starting in (0, 0)` comment. I'm sure you can figure out how to adjust those lines according to your needs.

Comment: Happy to see a solution using two pairs of x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Simple arrow sample

```java
/**
 * @param fromPoint end of the arrow
 * @param rotationDeg rotation angle of line
 * @param length arrow length
 * @param wingsAngleDeg wingspan of arrow
 * @return Path2D arrow shape
 */
public static Path2D createArrowForLine(
                 Point2D fromPoint, 
                 double rotationDeg, 
                 double length, 
                 double wingsAngleDeg) {

        double ax = fromPoint.getX();
        double ay = fromPoint.getY();

        double radB = Math.toRadians(-rotationDeg + wingsAngleDeg);
        double radC = Math.toRadians(-rotationDeg - wingsAngleDeg);

        Path2D resultPath = new Path2D.Double();
        resultPath.moveTo(length * Math.cos(radB) + ax, length * Math.sin(radB) + ay);
        resultPath.lineTo(ax, ay);
        resultPath.lineTo(length * Math.cos(radC) + ax, length * Math.sin(radC) + ay);
        return resultPath;
    }
```