# JFreeChart / Charting Library - Value Range Selection

Tags: charts, range, selection, jfreechart

I have to select a range of values in a bar chart by drawing a double-arrow outside of the CategoryPlot like on the image on the link below.

I've tried JFreeChart IntervalMarker and CategoryMarker, but they're not giving me the needed results and I have to find a way to draw the double-arrow (it's a requirement).

http://imageshack.com/a/img14/9935/kpij.png

Does someone has an idea how can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but you will have to do some work:

1. Use a `CategoryLineAnnotation` to draw a line between categories but as this annotation draws a line between the middle of the categories you are going to have to overide the `draw` method and change `CategoryAnchor.MIDDLE` to `CategoryAnchor.START` and `CategoryAnchor.END`.  This will draw the line you need.
2. You will need to implement a `Stroke` with arrows at both ends you can a find an example of an arrow end cap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112701/drawing-a-line-with-arrow-in-java), [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/jviewent/v8r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ilog.jviews.enterprise.doc/jviews-framework87/samples/java2d/srchtml/java2d/ArrowStroke.java.html) and in `CategoryPointerAnnotation#draw()`