# AffineTransform

Tags: java, user-interface

Well i use this code to paint my Graph's Edges, 
If the user wants to see the graph in its Flow mode then i draw arrows instead of lines,  all works perfectly, UNTILL I CHANGE WINDOW SIZE, then the arrows starting point (x1,y1) get moved unsynchronizely with my nodes leaving them unconnected, while drawLine() works perfect.

is this something to do with the AffineTransform?

(the arrows painting methodology is adopted from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488419/java-draw-a-ruler-line-with-tick-marks-at-90-degree-angle/3488474#3488474)) )

```
    void drawArrow(Graphics g1, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();
    int arrowSize = 5;
    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
    at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
    g.setTransform(at);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, len, 0);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    g.drawLine(len/3, arrowSize , len/3-3*arrowSize, 0);
    g.drawLine(len/3, -arrowSize , len/3-3*arrowSize, 0);
}
```

to whoever wandered how the paint Edge method look like:

```
    public void paintEdge(Graphics g) {
    Point uCenter = u.getCenter();
    Point vCenter = v.getCenter();
    g.setColor(color);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    if (mode==Mode.FLOW) {
        int minx=Math.min(uCenter.x, vCenter.x),miny=Math.min(uCenter.y, vCenter.y);
        int maxx=Math.max(uCenter.x, vCenter.x),maxy=Math.max(uCenter.y, vCenter.y);
        g2.drawString(""+ f + " / " + c,10+minx + (maxx-minx)/2,10+miny+ (maxy- miny)/2);
        drawArrow(g2,uCenter.x, uCenter.y, vCenter.x, vCenter.y);
    } else {
        g2.drawLine(uCenter.x, uCenter.y, vCenter.x, vCenter.y);
    }
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: the real problem is mentioned in the beginning, the code is just an illustration

Comment: in drawArrow you have Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create(); but I don't understand why you wouldn't just cast it like you do in paintEdge

Comment: i used some1 elses code for drawing that... so i dont know why he did that, see the link in the question

Comment: ill write a compileable code illustration then

Answer (score 2):

```
void drawArrow(Graphics2D g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    AffineTransform prev = g.getTransform();
    int arrowSize = 5;
    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
    at.rotate(angle);
    g.transform(at);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, len, 0);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    g.drawLine(len/3, arrowSize , len/3-3*arrowSize, 0);
    g.drawLine(len/3, -arrowSize , len/3-3*arrowSize, 0);
    g.setTransform(prev);
}
```

this is how its done, to whoever wondered.

the problem was, that i used g.setTransform(at); instead of g.transform(at); 
this was a hard one.